# add repository to ubuntu from terminal with pgp key

Tags: server, mono, repository

How do i add the pgp key from a terminal?

i have added the deb http://badgerports.org lucid main to sources.list 
and when i do a **sudo apt-get update** i get

```
W: GPG error: http://badgerports.org lucid Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C90F9CB90E1FAD0C
```

this is the key i need to add
http://badgerports.org/directhex.ppa.asc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This command will get the public key for the repo :

```
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key C90F9CB90E1FAD0C && gpg --export --armor C90F9CB90E1FAD0C | sudo apt-key add -
```

It works for any repository, you just have to replace the public key number in the command with the one from the error message.

Answer (score 8):

First run `wget http://badgerports.org/directhex.ppa.asc` and then run:

> sudo apt-key add directhex.ppa.asc

Answer (score 2):

There is also a script that automatically finds and adds all missing keys. It can be downloaded from Launchpad and is supported in Jaunty, Karmic, Lucid, Maverick.

[Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8/+files/launchpad-getkeys_0.1~webupd8~maverick_all.deb)

[Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8/+files/launchpad-getkeys_0.1~webupd8~lucid3_all.deb)

[Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8/+files/launchpad-getkeys_0.1~webupd8~karmic_all.deb)

[Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty Jackalope](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8/+files/launchpad-getkeys_0.1~webupd8~jaunty_all.deb)

After installation you simply run **sudo launchpad-getkeys**

Answer (score 0):

The answer didn't work in with the key of my repository because i wasn't in pgpkeys.mit.edu. The way it worked for me in ubuntu 20.04 was:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys PUT_THE_KEY_HERE
```